# System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute not recognizing custom role provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In my MVC 4 Web API project, I have a custom role provider that works as designed via `System.Web.Mvc.Authorize` attribute on my Home `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`.

On any `System.Web.Http.ApiController` with `System.Web.Http.Authorize` the custom role provider never gets called, always returning false. Is there a way to specify that the Web API AuthorizeAttribute pick up my custom role provider like the MVC AuthorizeAttribute?

Role Provider:

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{        
    //Overriden methods
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        //Always return "Master" for testing purposes
        return new string[] { "Master" };
    }

    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        //Always return true for testing purposes
        return true;
    }

    //Other overridden method stubs...
}
```

Web.config:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false" >
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="MyApp.SecurityExtensions.CustomRoleProvider, MyApp" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: It only hits it from the MVC Controller. Using `[System.Web.Http.Authorize(Roles = "Master")]` immediately evaluates to false from the API Controller

Comment: I would turn off caching for testing...

Comment: Cookies were expiring per-session, so I had just been closing the browser, but good point nonetheless in the event I forget to close the browser while debugging. I updated the OP to reflect turning off caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but this might help:

Both attributes work by querying the current pricipal. The MVC attribute uses HTTPContent.User, while the System.Web.http version uses Thread.CurrentPrincipal, but that difference is minor.

I'm not really familar with Web API, but I suspect that the RoleManagerModule is not running by the time the attribute fires, or you have not yet reached the PostAuthenticateRequest event, because in that event the Module replaces the Pricipal.

Are you sure you have some form of ASP authentication required for your WebAPI usage? If you don't have your WebAPI project configured to require some form of authentication, then obviously you will never reach the PostAuthenticateRequest event, and thus the RoleManagerModule will never kick-in.

The last possibility that comes to mind is that someting else is replacing the Principal after the RoleManagerModule does so.  If possible, temporarally remove the System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute, set a breakpoint in the controller, and detemine what class Thread.CurrentPrincipal has. That might give you a hint as to where it went wrong.

Comment: The third-party authentication library my client utilizes didn't bother to implement the `bool IsInRole(string role)` method after using the IPrincipal interface. Your suggestion to see if something was replacing the principal got me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use System.Web.**Http**.AuthorizeAttribute for Web API's controllers. Sample: http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-membership-provider/

Comment: I had scanned over that post previously, but why should I have to extend the AuthorizeAttribute in order for it to work with the API Controller? I can see the `System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal` is correctly setting the `ProviderName`

Comment: Just to clarify, as you can see in the comments on the OP, I responded to a comment which was subsequently deleted that I am using `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` and not `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` on my ApiController. I'll update the OP to make that clear. Thanks